# How to interpret the content model of DocBook elements in the documentation?

Tags: docbook, docbook-5

The official documentation's [1.1. Understanding Content Models](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/ref-elements.html#s2-cmintro) is very terse, and I'm having trouble understanding the content models of more complex elements. It brings the [`epigraph`](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/epigraph.html) element as an example:

> A
> validator uses the content models to determine if a
>           given document is valid. In order for a document to be valid, the
>           content of every element in the document must match
>           the content model for that element.
>
> In practical terms, match means that it must be
>           possible to expand the content model until it exactly matches the
>           sequence of elements in the document.
>
> For example, consider the content model of the
>           `epigraph`:
>
> `epigraph` ::=
> (`info`?<sup>db.titleforbidden.info</sup>,
> `attribution`?,(`literallayout` |
> *Paragraph elements*)+)

[`epigraph`](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/epigraph.html) is a fairly simple element, and it is straightforward to convert its content model from documentation page (see below) to the more compact form in [1.1. Understanding Content Models](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/ref-elements.html#s2-cmintro) (see above).

> epigraph ::= × ⏵
>
> - Sequence of:
>
>   - `info`? (db.titleforbidden.info)
>   - `attribution`?   + One or more of:
>
>     - literallayout
>     - Paragraph elements

I found the compact notation easier to interpret as the the long-form version in the documentation pages uses lists, and the longer they get, the harder it is to keep track of the "matching branches". For example, I was trying to figure out whether I could omit the [`title`](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/title.html) element when using [`preface`](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/preface.html), but didn't find it an easy task (its content model is 154 lines, see at the bottom).

Now, I could try to convert the model on the doc pages into the more compact form, but it would take considerable amount of time, especially if I have to go through this process with each element one by on. This could be automated, but another problem I have is that I'm not sure about some of the terms, such as "*Interleave of*": does it mean an unordered list with duplicate elements allowed? ("*Sequence of*" is clear: "take these elements or groups of elements in the following order".)

Tried to look up `preface`'s definition in the [`docbook/docbook`](https://github.com/docbook/docbook) repo, but it turns out that I'm not proficient enough to understand Relax NG and Schematron schemas yet... In the end, my original question got answered by finding a snippet in the [`docbook/defguide`](https://github.com/docbook/defguide/tree/docbook-5.2) repo; it helps comparing it with its long-form content model, but there must be an easier way to reason about it. (Plus, it can be hard to find specific DocBook examples online.)

```
<preface>
  <info>
    <title>Preface to the DocBook V5.1 Edition</title>
  </info>
  <para>This edition of ...</para>
</preface>
```

---

preface ::= × ⏵ ⏷

- Sequence of:

  - One of:

    - Sequence of:

      - Interleave of:

        - `title`
        - `titleabbrev`?
        - `subtitle`?
      - `info`? (db.titleforbidden.info)
    - `info` (db.titlereq.info)
  - Optional sequence of:

    - Zero or more of:

      - `bibliography`
      - `glossary`
      - `index`
      - `toc`
    - One of:

      - Sequence of:

        - One or more of:

          - `annotation`
          - `bridgehead`
          - `formalgroup`
          - `remark`
          - `revhistory`
          - *Indexing inlines* ⏵ ⏷
          - *Admonition elements* ⏵ ⏷
          - *Formal elements* ⏵ ⏷
          - *Graphic elements* ⏵ ⏷
          - *Informal elements* ⏵ ⏷
          - *List elements* ⏵ ⏷
          - *Paragraph elements* ⏵ ⏷
          - *Publishing elements* ⏵ ⏷
          - *Synopsis elements* ⏵ ⏷
          - *Technical elements* ⏵ ⏷
          - *Verbatim elements* ⏵ ⏷
        - Optionally one of:

          - Sequence of:

            - One or more of:

              - `section`
            - Zero or more of:

              - `simplesect`
          - One or more of:

            - `simplesect`
          - Sequence of:

            - One or more of:

              - `sect1`
            - Zero or more of:

              - `simplesect`
          - One or more of:

            - `refentry`
      - Sequence of:

        - One or more of:

          - `section`
        - Zero or more of:

          - `simplesect`
      - One or more of:

        - `simplesect`
      - Sequence of:

        - One or more of:

          - `sect1`
        - Zero or more of:

          - `simplesect`
      - One or more of:

        - `refentry`
    - Zero or more of:

      - `bibliography`
      - `glossary`
      - `index`
      - `toc`

Comment: Please recheck the question as the layout / indentation in the quoted parts if extremely important here and e.g. `attribution? + One or more of: ` on one line is not correct and should be on 2 lines!

Comment: @albert Thanks! It is now fixed, but just to copy paste the content model section takes up quite some time - which is kind of the point of the whole question.

Comment: @toraritte: I'm not sure I understand the question. The way you interpret it is the way you interpret anything vaguely complex: one step at a time, taking each piece in turn. Are you expecting people to give you an algorithm that converts the long-form content into short form? What kind of answer are you expecting from this question?

Comment: "*I was trying to figure out whether I could omit the title element when using preface, but didn't find it an easy task (its content model is 154 lines, see at the bottom).*" But only the first 8 lines involve things that would represent the title of a `preface`.